# redirect in add-on module redirecting me to admin control panel login form with # appended in URL

Tags: add-on, add-on-development, module, redirects

```
$this->EE->functions->redirect(BASE . AMP . 'C=addons_modules' . AMP . 'M=show_module_cp' . AMP . 'module=module_name_here' . '#tabsettings');
```

EE v2.9.2

I want to redirect the user after the person submits the form, then it fires off the redirect function.

When I append #tabsettings, it redirects me to the Admin CP login form. Here is the URL it directs me to:

```
http://project.dev/admin.php?/cp/login&return=Qz1hZGRvbnNfbW9kdWxlcyZhbXA7TT1zaG93X21vZHVsZV9jcCZhbXA7bW9kdWxlPWVlX3ZiX2ludGVncmF0aW9u#tabsettings
```

If I remove the #tabsettings, it will keep me within the module control panel, but I want it to load the settings view, which needs the #tabsettings to know which part of the view to load.

```
$this->EE->functions->redirect(BASE . AMP . 'C=addons_modules' . AMP . 'M=show_module_cp' . AMP . 'module=module_name_here');
```

Comment: The hashtag is getting in the way of the S parameter EE adds at the end of the url, if possible try using a GET variable instead. $url .= "&hashtag=tabsettings"

Answer (score 1):

[Brandon](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/30588/redirect-in-add-on-module-redirecting-me-to-admin-control-panel-login-form-with#comment32579_30588) is correct - EE does not like a hash in a redirect URL.

Instead, try using [flash data](https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/development/usage/session.html#flash-data-for-redirects) for this.

```
$this->EE->session->set_flashdata('selected-tab', 'settings');
$this->EE->functions->redirect(BASE . AMP . 'C=addons_modules' . AMP . 'M=show_module_cp' . AMP . 'module=module_name_here');
```

Then, in your module code:

```
if($tab = ee()->session->flashdata('selected-tab') && $tab == 'settings')
{
    // Add something here to your markup so that your JS will select the tab you want
}
```